# Create nested array/object from an array of strings by removing dots

Tags: php, arrays, json, algorithm, object

I am trying to solve a problem. Can anyone help me with that?

I have an array of strings as follows:

```
$data = [
    "name", "name.arun", "name.arun.bohra", "name.arun.test", "name.arun.bboohhrraa", "name.arun.bboohhrraa.user", "age", "lang", "lang.cpp"
];
```

What I want to do is to create an array from the data array/JSON object that should look like the following:

```
// This is not a valid JSON but rather an example of what result should be
[
  name => [
    arun => [
        bohra, test,
        bboohhrraa => [
            user
        ]
    ]
  ],

  age,

  lang => [ cpp ]
]
```

I have tried this in some ways, like looping through the array and inside the loop checking for `.` strings, but I consistently failed.

Can anyone help me with that?

Also, you can provide the solution in any language/syntax you wish.

Comment: Are `bohra`, `test`, and `user` string values in arrays or objects?

Comment: yes they can be string values in array or object

Comment: Hint: Sort the names according to the no. Of divisions to become in an increasing manner. This would make parent come before child.

Comment: Use the explode function in php.

Comment: We already have pages that demonstrate how to convert dot-syntax to arrays.